# Calculate time taken by each cpp file to compile in VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compilation

I am writing a tool which can be used to make the matrix for the current performance of the project.

For that I required to get the time taken by each file to get compiled.
I tried with the following option but didn't succeed :(

Tools->Options->Proejcts & Solutions -> VC++ Project Settings -> Build Timing-> Yes
From the above option I am able to get the whole time taken to build the solution but my problem is to get for each one.

**I am using VS2005**

So anyone is having any idea then pls revert back ASAP....

Answer (score 0):

I would replace cl.exe with a wrapper binary that takes the individual times. You'll have to write your own wrapper binary, but may consider using [vsextcomp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vsextcomp/) as a starting point.